# go get not downloading a module under a repository from BitBucket

Tags: go, bitbucket, go-modules, go-get

In have a git repo in bitbucket.org

```
reponame/
    .git/
    integration1/
    integration2/
    integration-common/
    └── util
        ├── go.mod
        └── readascii.go
```

The module directory is a subdirectory of the git repository.  The repository is tagged with `v0.0.1`.

Here's the go.mod

```
module bitbucket.org/orgname/reponame/integration-common/util
go 1.14
```

When I do `go get` for this module I get the following error

```
go get bitbucket.org/orgname/reponame/integration-common/util@v0.0.1

go: downloading bitbucket.org/orgname/reponame v0.0.1
go get bitbucket.org/orgname/reponame/integration-common/util@v0.0.1: module bitbucket.org/orgname/reponame@v0.0.1 found, but does not contain package bitbucket.org/orgname/reponame/integration-common/util
```

I can see the `integration-common/util/` directory in bitbucket.org under the tag `v0.0.1` if I look with the web browser.  The go.mod has the contents shown above.

What is even more odd is that go get does manage to download the other directories in the repository (`integration1/` and `integration2/`).  For some reason it thinks `v0.0.1` doesn't contain the `integration-common/` directory, even though bitbucket shows it there for that tag.

I download with ssh, not https, because https reqires 2fa on our bitbucket repo:

~/.gitconfig:

```
url "git@bitbucket.org:"]insteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/
```

I know bitbucket is weird when it comes to using go get.  Is there something I missed, or is this a bug with go get and bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

The tag `v0.0.1` applies to the module at the root of the repo (`bitbucket.org/orgname/reponame`).

The `go.mod` file in the `integration-common/util` subdirectory causes that subdirectory to become its own module, with its own space of versions and its own set of version tags, which would need to be of the form `integration-common/util/v0.0.1` (see https://golang.org/doc/modules/managing-source#tmp_4).

That is:

- The `v0.0.1` tag applies to module `bitbucket.org/orgname/reponame`, which does not contain the package because it is underneath a directory containing another `go.mod` file.
- The module `bitbucket.org/orgname/reponame/integration-common/util` exists and contains that package, but it does not have a version `v0.0.1` because the version tags for the subdirectory-module require an explicit prefix corresponding to that subdirectory.

In general, it is simplest to have only one `go.mod` file — at the repo root — and to avoid nesting additional modules in subdirectories.